# remove links from gnome pannel - ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gnome-panel

how to remove icon links from gnome panel?

[Please see attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OudR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1878851&p=11478706#post11478706) after a query on Google.

```
You need to press: super (windows key)+ alt + right-click over the 
launcher you want to remove and the option to remove it will appear.
```

Comment: @SethuM If you can please acept this answer and mark question as solved.